# autohotkey mouse click selecting wrong place

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I made this code to copy and paste some data with autohotkey and according to the documentation I have done it correctly but the mouse click start from y=0 rather than the number i sat it before. the loop works fine it increments by 30px each time but I need to make it start from the number specified.

```
^j::
    x_increment := 100
    y_increment := 30

    Loop, 15
    {
        clipboard := ""  ; Start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived.
        y:= 175
        y=y_offset
        x:= 173

        WinActivate, ahk_exe GoogleMapExtractor.exe
        sleep 500

        WinMaximize, ahk_exe GoogleMapExtractor.exe
        Sleep, 500

        MouseClick, left, x, y_offset, 1, 0, , 
        Sleep, 100

        MouseClick, left, x, y_offset, 1, 0, , 
        Sleep, 100
        
        MouseClick, left, x, y_offset, 1, 0, , 
        Sleep, 500
        
        Send ^a 
        sleep 500
        
        Send ^c
        sleep 500

        ;;;;;;;;;;;;;; EXCEL;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        WinActivate, ahk_exe Excel.exe
        WinWaitActive, ahk_exe Excel.exe
        
        Sleep 500
        Send ^v
        
        sleep 500
        Send {Down}
        
        sleep 500
        y_offset+=y_increment
    }
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
y=y_offset
```

Perhaps you meant to do this?

```
y += y_offset
```